# Drop down list menu

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox

Hi guys i want to make a drop down menu like that on a picture.
But i cant seem to do it. i tried many ways like combo box and drop down buttons but it does not look like that one in the picture. Ill be thankful to anyone who could help me. thanks

this is the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ma28.png

Comment: Do you have a repeater in your text?

Comment: you want a context menu or a combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your are looking for a [`MenuStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx) to add to your `form`, for more details see the following article: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p1.html